# Why cant my strings combine into one string

Tags: vb.net

I am making a little utility that is pulling monitor information from machines on my network. It is pulling all of the correct information. However, it's not merging the strings as I want. I added some msg boxes to my code to get readable output.
Here is a picture of the Output after each section.

[image: PICTURE OF EACH STRING]

This next one is a picture of the result when I try to merge all of the strings together.

[image: PICTURE OF MERGED STRINGS]

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I cannot merge the strings together. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the code

```
Public Sub Monitors()
    Dim Current As String = "Mobile-IT6799"
    Dim name As String = ""
    Dim model As String = ""
    Dim serial As String = ""
   
    Dim monitorName As String = ""
    Dim MonitorModel As String = ""
    Dim monitorserial As String = ""

    With MyConOptions
        .Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        .Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet
    End With
    Dim MyMgtScope1 As ManagementScope
    MyMgtScope1 = New ManagementScope("\\" & Current & "\root\WMI", MyConOptions)
    MyMgtScope1.Connect()

    MyObjSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(MyMgtScope1.Path.ToString, "Select * FROM WMIMonitorID")
    MyColl = MyObjSearcher.Get
    For Each MyObj In MyColl
        monitorName = ""
        MonitorModel = ""
        monitorserial = ""
        monitorName = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("InstanceName").ToString
        Select Case True
            Case monitorName.Contains("AAC")
                monitorName = "AcerView"
            Case monitorName.Contains("ACR")
                monitorName = "Acer"
            Case monitorName.Contains("ACI")
                monitorName = "Asus"
            Case monitorName.Contains("APP")
                monitorName = "Apple"
            Case monitorName.Contains("AUO")
                monitorName = "Asus"
            Case monitorName.Contains("CPQ")
                monitorName = "Compaq"
            Case monitorName.Contains("DEL")
                monitorName = "Dell"
            Case monitorName.Contains("HWP")
                monitorName = "HP"
            Case monitorName.Contains("LEN")
                monitorName = "Lenovo"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SAN")
                monitorName = "Samsung"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SAM")
                monitorName = "Samsung"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SNY")
                monitorName = "Sony"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SRC")
                monitorName = "Shamrock"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SUN")
                monitorName = "Sun"
            Case monitorName.Contains("SEC")
                monitorName = "Hewlett-Packard"
            Case monitorName.Contains("TAT")
                monitorName = "Tatung"
            Case monitorName.Contains("TOS")
                monitorName = "Toshiba"
            Case monitorName.Contains("TSB")
                monitorName = "Toshiba"
            Case monitorName.Contains("VSC")
                monitorName = "ViewSonic"
            Case monitorName.Contains("UNK")
                monitorName = "Unknown"
            Case monitorName.Contains("_YV")
                monitorName = "Fujitsu"
            Case Else
                monitorName = "Unknown"
        End Select
        MsgBox(monitorName)

        Dim arrModel() As UInt16 = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("UserFriendlyName")
        For Each j As UInt16 In arrModel
            MonitorModel &= Char.ConvertFromUtf32(j)
            j = Nothing
        Next
        MsgBox(MonitorModel)

        Dim arrSerial() As UInt16 = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumberID")
        For Each i As UInt16 In arrSerial
            monitorserial &= Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i)
            i = Nothing
        Next
        MsgBox(monitorserial)

        name &= " " & monitorName
        model &= " " & MonitorModel
        serial &= " " & monitorserial
        MyObj.Dispose()
    Next

    MsgBox(name)
    MsgBox(model)
    MsgBox(serial)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code still calls three separate messageboxes on three separate strings.

You *could* do this:

```
MsgBox($"{monitorName} {MonitorModel} {MonitorSerial}")
```

But what I'd *really* do is make a class:

```
Public Class MonitorInfo
    Public Property Make As String
    Public Property Model As String
    Public Property Serial As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub 'Placeholder

    Public Sub New(Make As String, Model As String, Serial As String)
        Me.Make = Make
        Me.Model = Model
        Me.Serial = Serial
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Make} {Model} {Serial}"
    End Function

    Public Shared Property MakeMap As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From { 
        {"AAC", "AcerView"},
        {"ACR", "Acer"},
        {"ACI", "Asus"},
        {"APP", "Apple"},
        {"CPQ", "Compaq"},
        {"DEL", "Dell"},
        {"HWP", "HP"},
        {"LEN", "Lenovo"},
        {"SAN", "Samsung"},
        {"SAM", "Samsugn"},
        {"SNY", "Sony"},
        {"SRC", "Shamrock"},
        {"SEC", "Hewlett-Packard"},
        {"TAT", "Tatung"},
        {"TOS", "Toshiba"},
        {"TSB", "Toshiba"},
        {"VSC", "ViewSonic"},
        {"UNK", "Unknown"},
        {"_YV", "Fujitsu"}
    }
End Class
```

And use it like this:

```vb
Public Iterator Function Monitors() As IEnumerable(Of MonitorInfo)
    With MyConOptions
        .Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        .Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet
    End With

    Dim Current As String = "Mobile-IT6799"
    Dim MyMgtScope1 As New ManagementScope($"\\{Current}\root\WMI", MyConOptions)
    MyMgtScope1.Connect()
    Dim MyObjSearcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(MyMgtScope1.Path.ToString, "Select * FROM WMIMonitorID")

    Dim MyColl = MyObjSearcher.Get
    For Each monitor In MyColl
        Dim Make As String = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("InstanceName").ToString()
        If Not MonitorInfo.MakeMap.TryGetValue(Make, Make) Then
            Make = "Unknown"
        End If

        Dim arrModel() As UInt16 = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("UserFriendlyName")
        Dim Model As New String(arrModel.Select(Char.ConvertFromUtf32).ToArray())

        Dim arrSerial() As UInt16 = MyObj.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumberID")
        Dim Serial As New String(arrSerial.Select(Char.ConvertFromUtf32).ToArray())

        Dim result As New MonitorInfo(Make, Model, Serial)
        MsgBox(result) 'comment out when tested
        Yield result
        monitor.Dispose()
    Next    
End Function
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the MonitorName and MonitorModel but leaves out the Monitorserial. I know Monitorserial has data in it because if I type out 
`MsgBox($"{monitorserial}")`
 I get the serial number but when i use 
`MsgBox($"{monitorName} {MonitorModel} {monitorserial}")`
 I only get the name and Model

Comment: IIRC, those `UInt16[]` represent all ASCII values, so the conversion could be, e.g., `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arrModel.TakeWhile(ui => ui != 0).Select(ui => Convert.ToByte(ui)).ToArray());`

Comment: Suggestion, dispose objects when done with them, for example: `MyObjSearcher.Dispose()`.